# partially decrypted string & is gibberish

Tags: java, encryption, derby, bouncycastle

I'm using embedded Derby that requires `no-padding` & `blockSize=8` bytes, along with Bouncy Castle.

In below code the problems are:

1. The `byteArray` length of the encrypted `String` is 20 bytes. The `byteArray` length retrieved from DB is 20 bytes, yet the `encryptBlock` value gives me only 8 bytes of length.
2. Even the 8 bytes are gibberish .
3. How to embed the IV with the cypherText?

```
private CFBBlockCipher cipher() {

    secureRandom = new SecureRandom(KEY);
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[32];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(randomBytes);

    kgp = new KeyGenerationParameters(secureRandom, 256);

    ckg = new CipherKeyGenerator();
    ckg.init(kgp);

    sk = ckg.generateKey();

    /* Initialize cipher parameters....with key & the IV */
    cipherParameters = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(sk), IVBYTES); //IVYTES array
    /*3- Generate the encryption & decryption ciphers*/
    CFBB = CFBBlockCipher(new AESEngine(), BITBLOCKSIZE); //BITBLOCKSIZE =64bit

    byte[] cfbbMoneyOneCurrentIV = CFBB.getCurrentIV();

    /*4- initialize the cipher*/
    CFBB.init(true, cipherParameters);

    return CFBB;
}

private void resetCipher() {
    if (CFBB != null) {
        CFBB.reset();
    }
}

private byte[] encrypt(CFBBlockCipher CFBB,String stringOne) {
    this.CFBB=CFBB;
    /*1- get the stream data to be ciphered*/            
        stringOneByteArray = stringOne.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        toSaveByteArray = new byte[stringOneByteArray.length];
        int encryptBlock = CFBB.encryptBlock(stringOneByteArray, 0, toSaveByteArray, 0);
        System.out.println("encryptBlock length is :"+encryptBlock);          

    resetCipher();
    return toSaveByteArray;
}

private InputStream decrypt(CFBBlockCipher CFBB) {
    this.CFBB=CFBB;
    //connect to DB, get column data/
    String getData = "select moneyEditor from settingsTable where id=1";
    try {
        stmtOne = conn.createStatement();
        boolean execute = stmtOne.execute(getData);
        rsOne = stmtOne.getResultSet();
        while (rsOne.next()) {
            rsByteArray = rsOne.getBytes("moneyEditor");
            if (rsByteArray != null) {
                System.out.println("rsByteArray length is :" + rsByteArray.length);

                toSaveDecryptByteArray = new byte[rsByteArray.length];
                int decryptedByteArrayLength;
                decryptedByteArrayLength = CFBB.decryptBlock(rsByteArray, 0, toSaveDecryptByteArray, 0);
                System.out.println("decryptedByteArrayLength is :" + decryptedByteArrayLength);
                isFromDecoded = new ByteArrayInputStream(toSaveDecryptByteArray);

            } else {
                isFromDecoded = null;
            }
        }
        rsOne.close();
        resetCipher();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FrontFace.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return isFromDecoded;
}
```

Comment: 3. The general way to embed the IV is to pre-fix the encrypted text with it, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: As the name says, `encryptBlock` processes a block which is 8 byte in your case, because you initialized CFB with a 64 bit segment size

Comment: @Artjom..Derby Encryption states that the block size should be 8bytes...so how in this case would I decrypt all ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how this code relates to Apache Derby. AES has a block size of 16 bytes. The CFB mode *can* transform that to a segment size of 8 bytes. I've seen some documentation where DES and Blowfish are mentioned which both have a block size of 8 bytes. I have no idea, what you're trying to do and why you're writing this code at all.

Comment: @Artjom..Thanks ...actually Derby docs state https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/security/index.html...and CFBBLockCipher(BlockCipher,BitBlockSize)...I do agree with you that the issue is in cipher initialization ...

Comment: Using DES is like using nothing :)

Comment: I share @Artjom B's confusion. Precisely **where** in the Derby docs are you looking? Please edit your question to include the **specific** documentation page, not just a link to the entire Derby Security Guide.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton... The link to show Derby requires when using other algorithm should be with block cipher and 8bytes block size... And that what prompts me to use 64bit of length at CFBBlockCipher().